# Crystal report showing blank gaps even the suppress blank space is ticked

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, reporting, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

I have crystal report in which sections do not have any gaps, i have marked pagination to false as well. But when i preview my report it shows like this, even i have ticked suppress blank section.

Please view image and let me know how to deal with it.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your report design plz?

Comment: make sure you ticked on right section

Answer (score -1):

Gaps occurred when we use *Keep Together* as true for sections, crystal report manages to keep the objects together and does not allow objects to move dynamically which causes extra spacing and big gaps. 
If you are looking to make a contiguous report, it's section must not have *Keep Together* as true, although it is confusing by meaning, but this is how it works.

Please see image below to find how i fixed this issue.
[image]